# Jupyter themes on Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, themes, jupyter

when I'm using Jupyter Notebook I use `chesterish` theme. I was wondering if its possible to have the theme I use on Jupyter also for Pycharm in order to have same theme and colors on both platform.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what chesterish theme looks like?

Comment: @bad_coder here is the screenshot. My question was more about importing all the existing themes in Jupyter to Pycharm, but now I realized that changing by hand the colors one by one on my own its fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize that doing it "by hand" was pretty simple so in the end the result is quite satisfying (on the left the original, on the right my work):

[image]

Just go to `Preferences>Editor>Color Scheme>Python`:

[image]

And for the general theme I use `Nord`.

**Edit:**

I write down here all the colors that I have set to replicate Chesterish theme:

for `Keyword` (ex. `def`,`class`,`if`,`else`) its 52B3FC

for `Function definition` (ex. `my_function`) its EDD46A

for `Number` (ex. `1296`) its 57C1ED

for `Operation sign` (ex. `+,-,:,*`) its 52B3FC

for `Text (unicode)` (ex. `"hi my name is"`) its 64B987

for `Built-in name` (ex. `str,len,`) its DF7F86

Comment: This is what I was going to recommend. Search for a similar theme and adapt the minor differences.

Comment: Can you share your color schema?

Comment: I have edited my answer with all the colors